# creating link between turtles that are a distance apart

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a classroom. In a classroom there are about 90 seats, 20 lights, 20 fans and 4 ACs. I create num-of-students where each student has an assigned random entry-time. When each student enters after a random time and sits on a seat the corresponding (in-radius)light or fan or ac turn on. SO I want to link each student to its (in-radius) light, fan and AC. Then I can find the on time of each appliance(light, fan and AC).

How can I create link from the students to each corresponding (in-radius 4) light, fan and AC?

```
breed [lights light] 
breed [fans fan]
breed [acs ac ]
breed [students student ]

 to setup

create-students num-of-students
    ..
    ..

  ask students 
      [  create-link-with lights in-radius 4
          create-link-with fans in-radius 4
         create-link-with fans in-radius 9 ]  
      end
```

This code is not working. Thank you!

Comment: you didn't actually say what you mean by 'not working'. Does it produce an error message? If so, what is the message? Does it not create links? Does it create links between the wrong things? My guess is that you get an error message. Try `create-links-with` instead of `create-link-with`. There are potentially multiple lights and fans, but the syntax you are using creates a link with exactly one other agent and you have to tell NetLogo the identifier for that agent. You want the `agentset` form.

Comment: Links are not being created. There is no error sign but "show count links" gives 0 links. Thus no links are being created although there are lights and fans close to the students.

Comment: If you are not getting an error using `create-link-with` even though the correct syntax is `create-links-with`, then it's not even trying to create the links. You will need to provide more of your setup procedure.

Comment: sorry my bad it was giving an error using create-link-with but I corrected it by create-links-with. But still there are no links being created. There are zero links created.

Comment: The code you have will create links, so the problem must be that there are no lights or fans within the distance given. Can we see more of your code, where you create the fans etc.

Comment: I found the problem. Thank you very much.